# PHP IntlDateFormatter::parse Output Timezone

Tags: php, time, timezone

I have the following PHP code:

```
$date = 'janvier 1, 2014 à 5:00PM';
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('fr_CA', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'America/Toronto', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN, 'MMMM d, yyyy 'à' h:mma');
$date = $formatter->parse($date);
var_dump($date);
```

The output is:

```
int(1388613600)
```

This appears to be a UNIX timestamp, which is always UTC, Right? So it's automatically being converted from America/Toronto?

Just confirming that I have this correct. I don't have a lot of experience with PHP and time zones, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: `echo date('r', 1388613600)` will show you exactly what php thinks it is. if it is a different time zone, it won't be coming out as 5pm like in your original string.

Comment: Output is `Wed, 01 Jan 2014 22:00:00 +0000`. Thank you.

Comment: Toront's UTC-4 this time of year, isn't it? you'd think it'd come out 1pm or something.

Comment: This time of year, yes, I think so. But what about Jan 1st? ;)

Comment: If it was UTC-4, it would come out at 6pm, not 1pm.  But on Jan 1st 2014, it was UTC-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  The timestamp is a UNIX timestamp.  That is - the number of whole seconds since Jan 1, 1970 UTC, not accounting for leap seconds.

You can verify the timestamp using a site like [epochconverter.com](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

```
1388613600 = 2014-01-01T22:00:00Z
```

Then you can check the time zone details at [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com).

- In January 2014, [Toronto was on EST](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/toronto), which is UTC-05:00.
- [This calculation](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20140101T22&p1=0&p2=250) clearly verifies that 22:00 UTC is 5:00 PM EST.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc B mentioned, `date('r', 1388613600)` returned a formatted version of the date including the timezone offset which was set to `+0000`.

The output is in fact UTC.

Thanks Marc!